# Can Cassandra LWTs have an IF part in terms of a PRIMARY KEY

Tags: java, transactions, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Do Cassandra lightweight transactions use an implied SET, and so can not have an IF part in terms of a primary key?

I ask because the Datastax Cassandra Java driver (version 2.1.5) throws an `InvalidQueryException` while I'm preparing a statement. The exception message is clear enough:

> PRIMARY KEY part name found in SET part

Except that the query it is preparing does *not* attempt to SET the primary key. The query is

```
 UPDATE operator SET password = :password WHERE name = :name IF name = :name;
```

As you can see, the query does SET `password` and does not set `name`; `name` is the primary key for the `operator` table. The exception message would make sense only if the `IF name = :name` of the lightweight transaction was implemented using a `SET name = ...`.

If I remove the `IF name = :name` part from the query, the driver does not complain about trying to SET the primry key.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: PRIMARY KEY part name found in SET part; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: PRIMARY KEY part name found in SET part
    at com.example.application.datalayer.DriverExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(DriverExceptionTranslator.java:200) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.datalayer.DriverExceptionTranslator$ExceptionTranslationAdvice.afterThrowing(DriverExceptionTranslator.java:50) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invokeHandlerMethod(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:145) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:130) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.$Proxy0.addUser(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.Add.tryToAddUser(Add.java:294) [application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.Add.performOperation(Add.java:266) [application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.Mode.run(Mode.java:812) [application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.Mode.runProgram(Mode.java:79) [application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.Add.main(Add.java:63) [application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: PRIMARY KEY part name found in SET part
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:79) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.CassandraUserRepository$SessionAdapter.(CassandraUserRepository.java:80) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.CassandraUserRepository.getSessionAdapter(CassandraUserRepository.java:447) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.application.user.CassandraUserRepository.addUser(CassandraUserRepository.java:317) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:125) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: PRIMARY KEY part name found in SET part
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:103) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$1.apply(SessionManager.java:185) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$1.apply(SessionManager.java:160) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$1.apply(Futures.java:720) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:859) ~[application-user.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a condition on a partition key column (`IF name = 'foo'`), because that column is already restricted in the where clause (`WHERE name = 'foo'`).

There is indeed a problem with the error message. This has apparently been fixed, with Cassandra 2.1.4 I get: `PRIMARY KEY column 'name' cannot have IF conditions`.

Comment: [CASSANDRA-7804](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7804), fixed in 2.0.11 and 2.1.1.